# How can I change the background video in the header depending on the selected theme (react)?

Tags: reactjs

I have a video embedded in the background in the header of the site for react. Also, with the help of hooks, a dark and light theme is made. How can I change the background video in the header depending on the selected theme?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import './header.css';
import CTA from './CTA';
import logo from '../../assets/232.png'
import HeaderSocials from './HeaderSocials';
import {IoBasketballOutline, IoBasketballSharp} from 'react-icons/io5';
import {useTheme} from '../../hooks/use-theme';
import backvideo from '../../assets/white.mp4';
import backvideo2 from '../../assets/black.mp4';

const Header = () => {

    const {setTheme} = useTheme()
    const handleLightThemeClick = () => {
        setTheme('light')
    }
    const handleDarkThemeClick = () => {
        setTheme('dark')
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <video autoPlay loop muted><source src={backvideo} type='video/mp4'/></video>
            <div className='container header__container'>
                <div className='theme__icons' >
                    <motion.button whileHover={{scale: 1.1}} onClick={handleLightThemeClick} className='theme__toggle'><IoBasketballOutline/></motion.button>
                    <motion.button whileHover={{scale: 1.1}} onClick={handleDarkThemeClick} className='theme__toggle'><IoBasketballSharp/></motion.button>
                </div>
```

I tried to write a condition if setTheme('light') then  else

in fact, this is what I need, maybe I made a mistake in the code, can someone help me write the condition correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import lightvideo from '../../assets/white.mp4';
import darkvideo from '../../assets/black.mp4';

const backvideo = '';

const {setTheme} = useTheme()
    const handleLightThemeClick = () => {
        setTheme('light')


        backvideo = lightvideo;
    }
    const handleDarkThemeClick = () => {
        setTheme('dark')


        backvideo = darkvideo
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <video autoPlay loop muted><source src={backvideo} type='video/mp4'/></video>
```

im no reactjs expert. but this should work
or atleast give you a great push into the right direction

Comment: Thank you. Seems like you right, but need to use let instead of const. Anyways if i use src={backvideo} in render result <source src="" type="video/mp4">..need to think